AgdaはなぜTypeではなくSetを使うのでしょうか？
‘Hello world’ in Agda — Agda 2.6.5 documentation
では、下記のようにあたりまえのようにSetを用いています。

data Greeting : Set where
 hello : Greeting

greet : Greeting
greet = hello


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language) には下記がありました。

Agda is based on Zhaohui Luo's unified theory of dependent types (UTT),[7] a type theory similar to Martin-Löf type theory.

UTTというMartin-Löf type theoryに似たものに基づいているとのことです。
Type（型）は、Set（集合）とは似ているけど、別物という認識なのですが、UTTやMartin-Löf type theoryは集合を扱っているのでしょうか？それとも、Agdaの何かしらの意図でしょうか？

補足情報としては日本語のWikipediaだと
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda

Agda（アグダ）は、定理証明器、すなわち数学的な証明を検証するコンピュータプログラムであり、ペール・マルティン＝レーフの型理論の一種における構成的証明構築のための対話的システムである。機能的には、依存型をもつ関数型プログラミング言語であるともみなすこともできる。1990年代よりチャルマース工科大学で主に開発されている。

とあるので、特にUTTは登場していませんでした。

他の例として、たとえば下記の動画では15分22秒あたりに強引に(?)
Agda Lecture 1: Introduction to Agda, dependent types and functions -- HoTTEST Summer School 2022
Type = Set

としていますが、普通はSetを使うのではないかというようなことも話されていました。

追記：
https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/4189/why-does-agda-use-set-instead-of-type
にも質問しました。
